How do I prevent the rotation and vertical movement of an object by collision?
I have this issue in cannon.js where when a cube runs into an object, that cube just flies over it, instead of staying on the floor. Also, the red physics box is turning and moving. How would I make the cube stay on the floor, and the red physics box to not turn
https://streamable.com/pbqis3
On a side note, I am setting the position and quaternion to be the exact same, why is it different?
cube.position.copy(boxBody.position);
cube.quaternion.copy(boxBody.quaternion);

You can demo test it here: https://ethantwu.com/minigames/3dgame
And all of the code is here: https://github.com/LeftClickMage/ethantwu.com/blob/main/minigames/test3d.js
